# How to convert a color fill layer into a mask?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I created several color fill layers that I thought were layer masks, is it possible to change it to layer masks?

The color fills are silhouettes, so a basic shape that looks like a layer mask.
any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+click the layer *thumbnail* in the **Layers Panel**.

Highlight the layer you want to add a mask to in the **Layers Panel**.

Click the `New Mask` icon at the bottom of the **Layers Panel**.

Turn off the *visibility* for the layer with the shape.

[image]

Comment: Double facepalm.

Comment: HA!!!!!!!! That hadn't even occurred to me :)